# Assigning logical value to values higher than given threshold for each case across each year

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

I have a data frame resembling the extract below:

```
set.seed(1)
smpl_df <- data.frame(year = c(1500:2011), case = LETTERS[1:4])
smpl_df$var_one <- sample(100, size = nrow(smpl_df), replace = TRUE)
```

I'm interested in adding one more column to this data frame. I'm interested in the column to take the value `1` if the values in the column `var_one` were higher than a given threshold for all of the consecutive years represented in the data set. For example, in its present format the table looks like that:

```
 head(smpl_df)
  year case var_one
1 1500    A      27
2 1501    B      38
3 1502    C      58
4 1503    D      91
5 1504    A      21
6 1505    B      90
```

I would like to add a column to the data table *(values for the new column are not right, just introduced as a way of example)*:

```
  year case var_one var_one_higher_than_80_for_all_yrs_for_this_case
1 1500    A      27 0
2 1501    B      38 0
3 1502    C      58 0
4 1503    D      91 1
5 1504    A      21 0
6 1505    B      90 1
```

---

## *Edit*

To add to the post following useful points expressed in the comments below. The long table that I'm currently working with could be obtained from the wide table below. In the example below, I added column **NewColumn** that takes values `Yes` if for a given case value was higher than **2** and `No` if the value was lower or equal **2** for all the years. I want to achieve the same effect but on my long table (`sample_df`).

[image: original wide table]

### *Edit 2*

Following the useful comments concerning the desired final output, my intention is to generate a column that would correspond to the last column in the table below.

[image: Sample Final Table]

Comment: It is an Heaviside function. Check `Heaviside` function in `fBasics` for example.

Comment: You should use `set.seed` when using `sample`. Your desired output is also not very clear to me.

Comment: @DavidArenburg point taken with respect to the `set.seed`. To clarify with respect to the output I would like for the new column to take value `1` if, for example, values of the `var_one` for all the `years` were higher than, let it be, `80`. Analogously, if values of the `var_one` for all the `years` for the case `B` were higher than `80` I would like for the new column to take the value `1`. I will amend my post to reflect your comments. Thank you for showing the interest.

Comment: Based on the description perhaps `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(case) %>% mutate(x = as.integer(all(var_one > 80)))` though your example output is different

Comment: But in your desired output you assigned `1` to cases when `var_one` isn't higher than 80 as well. Also, you mentioned something regarding "consecutive" which I don't see reflected in your description.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, thanks for your feedback. This is now amended, I introduced some figures just to show how the end result should look but I should caveat that the figures are not right.

Comment: Your new column is called `var_one_higher_than_80_for_all_yrs_for_this_case` but it seems that you just checking per row if `var_one` is higher than 80 no? In other words, from your desired output it seems that all you need is just `smpl_df$newvar <- +(smpl_df$var_one > 80)` while your table below indicates that you want to check per case rather per row, in other words, something like `smpl_df$newvar <- with(smpl_df, ave(var_one, case, FUN = function(x) all(x > 80)))`. So still confusing.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, the output table is just an example. To clarify, I want to check each case across all the years.

Comment: So you want the `ave` option? Or the option mentioned by docendo discimus? You can do it very easily using `data.table` too.

Comment: @docendodiscimus I tried the code: `smpl_df <- smpl_df %>% group_by(case) %>% mutate(x = as.integer(all(var_one > 1)))` which should return values `1` for `x` (as all values are higher than `1`) but `table(smpl_df$x)` returns values *256* and *256*.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, in a word I would like for the new rows next to the case `A` take value `1` if all all the values  for the `var_one` for that particular case (`A`) are higher than a threshold (let it be 80). This would enable me to say something on the lines: *across the period represented in the data values for `X` number of cases where always higher than `Y`*. I'm intending to do other things as well with this data so I only need identifier indicating cases that have values higher than the threshold.

Comment: You have all the solutions in the comments already. You can add `library(data.table) ; setDT(smpl_df)[, res := +(all(var_one > 80)), by = case]` and you good to go.

Comment: @DavidArenburg thanks very much the `setDT` solution works like a charm. For threshold `2` there were `128` instances, as per `table(smpl_df$res)`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe be helpful ifelse structure:
`smpl_df$var_one_higher <- ifelse("your func",1,0)`